# Choosing a project for a fresh graduate student

Tags: masters, supervision, research-topic

I am starting to advise a new graduate student for M.Sc. degree (in theoretical computer science), and I am considering what should be the first problem they should work on.

One option is a small and focused project that fits within a larger work that I recently did with a colleague. The advantage is that the student will likely succeed, since it is a relatively simple problem. Also, if the paper gets accepted, the student will have a publication in an early stage, which is encouraging. The disadvantage is that the problem is not sufficiently significant on its own - only as a part of the larger project. I am not sure how the student will put this in his thesis - he cannot put the entire paper in the thesis since it's not his own work.

Another option is a larger and completely new project. The advantage is that, if the student succeeds, it will be entirely his own work. The disadvantage is that it is a harder problem, so the student might get stuck and be discouraged.

What are some guidelines for selecting a good first project for a starting graduate student?

Comment: What is the timescale for this project? Is it limited to a term or is it open-ended?

Comment: Some of what you suggest/ask here depends entirely on university rules: "I am not sure how the student will put this in his thesis ...". Those rules can vary.

Comment: The timescale for master's thesis is 2 years. For the small project, I would like to submit the paper in some 4-6 months, but this is flexible.

Comment: My model is to start a student off on a small project.  The project must be within the reach of the student's current knowledge.  I use this project to train the student in the art of research.  Usually, after the first project, a student becomes a semi-competent researcher.

Comment: I think this also depends on the amount of time you are (realistically) able to spend on this student and their MSc. If you have the time, then the larger/newer project might be the way to go, so you can guide them a bit more to prevent them from getting stuck/discouraged.